# Sort array of points into squares

Tags: c#, coordinates, coordinate-systems

So if I have an array of points that are all evenly placed. How can I sort the array into squares so that `points[0]` to `points[n]` and `points[n]` to `points[n+n]` are squares.

My (not working) try in C#:

```
class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var points = new List<Point>();
        int width = 6;
        int height = 6;
        int n = 9;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point() { x = x, y = y });
            }
        }

        points = points.OrderBy((point) => (point.x - (point.x % (n / 2))) + (point.y - (point.y % (n / 2)))).ToList();

        foreach (Point point in points.Take(n))
        {
            Console.Write($"{point.x},{point.y} ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
        // outputs 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 1,0 1,1 1,2 1,3 2,0
        // should output 0,0 0,1 0,2 1,0 1,1 1,2 2,0 2,1 2,2

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: *"the first n points would make a square n units big"* I can't imagine how you're going to make a square of size 2 with only 2 points. You need 4 points to make a square, right?

Comment: @RufusL need to work on my explanation skills. Should be more understandable now.